# How to make a CCSprite disappear after a time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an iOS game.  Part of the goal of the game is to collect coins.  I generate the coins randomly, and keep track of them with an NSMutable array.  I know how to handle the coins if they are collected, but I want the coins to disappear from the screen after 10 seconds if they are not collected so that they are not permanently displayed or remembered in the NSMutable array.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disappear after 10 seconds from appear if they are not collected, you can run CCAction on them.
`[SpriteCoin runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSprite:)]];`

you will remove it with this function:

`-(void) removeSprite:(id)sender`
`{ [self removeChild:sender cleanup:YES]; }`